# Detox + React Native Android launches to blank screen

Tags: android, react-native, detox

## Problem

While I have detox working great on iOS, my react-native android detox build launches a blank screen when opened via the detox cli.

It may be worth mentioning neither `cmd + m` or `rr` reload in this state.

## Package.json

```
  "react-native": "0.51.0",
  ...
  "detox": "^7.0.0-alpha.0",
  ...
  "android.emu.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
    "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
    "type": "android.emulator",
    "name": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
  },
```

## Troubleshooting

When running

```
detox test -c android.emu.debug --loglevel verbose
```

the android apk installs, launches, but gets stuck at a blank screen.

#### Detox logs

```
detox info 15:26:02: server listening on localhost:63324...
detox verb ws onOpen [object Object]
detox verb ws send: {"type":"login","params":{"sessionId":"300068b9-c44f-8b8a-81cb-73f8c66b0752","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws onMessage: {"type":"loginSuccess","params":{"sessionId":"300068b9-c44f-8b8a-81cb-73f8c66b0752","role":"tester"},"messageId":0}
detox verb ws
detox verb 1: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds --verbose
detox verb 1: stdout: Nexus_5X_API_26
detox verb 1: stdout:
detox verb /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -verbose -gpu host -no-audio @Nexus_5X_API_26
detox verb 2: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb  devices
detox verb 2: stdout: List of devices attached
detox verb 2: stdout: emulator-5554 device
detox verb 2: stdout:
detox verb 2: stdout:
detox verb 3: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
detox verb 3: stdout: 1
detox verb 3: stdout:
detox verb 4: /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell input keyevent 82
detox verb adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w -r -e detoxServer ws://localhost:63324 -e detoxSessionId 300068b9-c44f-8b8a-81cb-73f8c66b0752 -e debug false com.mypackage.mobile.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
detox verb Instrumentation spawned, childProcess.pid:  24565
detox verb ws send: {"type":"isReady","params":{},"messageId":-1000}
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  com.mypackage.mobile.DetoxTest:
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=runDetoxTests
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.mypackage.mobile.DetoxTest
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:
```

And after 2 minutes

```
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:  INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
detox verb Instrumentation stdout:
detox verb instrumentationProcess terminated due to receipt of signal null
  1) "before all" hook: _callee

  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook: _callee:
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.





  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) "before all" hook: _callee:
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

#### Android logs

From running `react-native log-android`

```
01-17 15:11:01.053  5248  5318 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
01-17 15:11:01.055  5248  5318 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
01-17 15:11:01.060  5248  5318 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
01-17 15:11:01.061  5248  5318 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
01-17 15:11:01.061  5248  5323 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
01-17 15:11:01.061  5248  5323 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
01-17 15:11:01.065  5248  5323 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
```

#### Emulator behavior

Sometime after the above logs the app will time out so I kill it.  When I launch the same app (same apk installed by detox) from the emulator it works as expected!

The logs from `react-native log-android`, when the apk launches as expected, has the extra line

```
01-17 15:24:10.207  6447  6530 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "MyApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
```

At this point I know the apk is good so I've tried the `--reuse` flag but same problem.

#### DetoxTest.java

```
package com.mypackage.mobile;
import android.support.test.filters.LargeTest;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import com.wix.detox.Detox;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class DetoxTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);

    @Test
    public void runDetoxTests() throws InterruptedException {
        Detox.runTests(mActivityRule);
    }
}
```

## Question

Does anyone know how to solve it so that, when running via detox cli, the app will launch as expected instead of the blank screen I'm getting?  If not is there a good next step I can take, something to isolate launching the app from DetoxTest.java?

Comment: Im having this same issue on production release mode only. Ever figure out a fix?

Comment: @AlexHarrison While I haven't used detox in years now, I'm fairly certain there were some network calls behind a corporate proxy that never finished loading and Detox was waiting for them to finish under the hood.  Once we resolved this we were able to move forward.  While our use cases may differ, just know that If detox thinks the app is doing something it'll wait.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not launching there is probably a good chance that the Android app is not building properly. Can you make sure that your "android.emu.debug" is nested properly under detox.configurations in your `package.json` like this

```
"detox": {
    "configurations": {
        "android.emu.debug": {
            "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
            "build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..",
            "type": "android.emulator",
            "name": "Nexus_5X_API_26"
        },
    }
}
```

Also, check to make sure you have the following in your `android/app/build.gradle`

```
androidTestImplementation(project(path: ":detox"))
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Android. Part of what helped me was using this:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    device.reloadReactNative();
});
```

Also I'm testing with the emulator opened before running my tests